# Change Opacity of an Unclicked Element

Tags: jquery, click, jquery-animate, opacity

I have some elements on my webpage and I want that when I click one of the elements, the others (who are unclicked) have their opacity changed.

Here is the HTML code of one element :

```
<div class="element hover download" id="_4>
    <div class="front">
        <div class="element-image-front">
            <img src="./Post thumbnail images/raspberryPiboard.JPG"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="back">
        <a class="link" href="#/portfolio/chicken.html" onclick="gestionClic('compteur11');"><div class="element-image-back">
        <div class="element-image-back">
            <img src="./Post thumbnail images/raspberryPiboard.JPG"/>
        </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I click on an element this is the `class="link"` that is clicked.

I tried this but it doesn't work :

```
$('.link').click(function() {
    $('.element').siblings().stop().animate({opacity: 0.4}, 300);
    $('.link').click(function() {
        $not('.element').stop().animate({opacity: 1.0}, 300);
    });
});
```

Comment: That's strange, your jQuery code looks totally good to me ?

Comment: But it really don't work...

Comment: Is this a typo: `$(this).child().$('.element-image-front')`? I'm pretty sure there shouldn't be another `$` in the chained methods.

Comment: Like this : $('.link').click(function() {
        $('.element').siblings().stop().animate({opacity: 0.4}, 300);
        $('.link').click(function() {
        $not('.element').stop().animate({opacity: 1.0}, 300);
        });
});  It near works. But all element become to 0.4 opacity. I don't know how get the parent div of the clicked link...

Answer (score 0):

**First :** Clean your HTML elements !

**Second :** Work at my demo

```
$('.element > img').click(function () {
    $(this).animate({opacity:0.4}).siblings().animate({opacity:1});
});
```

After you cleaned up your HTML like...

```
<div class="element">
    <img src="{SRC}">
    <img src="{SRC}">
</div>
```

So you can use [.siblings()](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/)

**Demo :** http://jsfiddle.net/l2aelba/nq3CN/

---

If you really want to use your uncleaned HTML, so just do like this...

```
$('.element img').click(function () {
     $('.element').find("img").not(this).animate({opacity:1});
    $(this).animate({opacity:0.4});
});
```

**Demo :** http://jsfiddle.net/l2aelba/nq3CN/1/

---

**Example in your case :**

```
$('.element > .back > .link').click(function () {
    $(this).animate({opacity:1});
    $(this).parents(".element").find(".front > .element-image-front").animate({opacity:0.3});
});
```

**Click another :**

```
$('.element > .front > .element-image-front').click(function () {
    $(this).animate({opacity:1});
    $(this).parents(".element").find(".back > .link").animate({opacity:0.3});
});
```

Should be done in one function but your HTML is unclear. So just code 2 functions for 100% work and 100% absolute focus elements right

**Demo :** http://jsfiddle.net/l2aelba/nq3CN/2/

Comment: Thank you for your help. However the element that is clicked is : class="link" (because I have a hover effect on my .element). The opacity can be applied on the entire element : class="element". So I need to get the parent class or id of the clicked class="link"...

Comment: My HTML is clean! This is because I have a click count a 3D flip effect, an overlay effect an other things... However, when the element is click, this the class="link" that is clicked. I need to apply opacity of the children class="element or his id. I don't know how to get the parent of the div class="link" clicked

Comment: `$(".link").parents(".element");` (Find parent class name ELEMENT until found , closest)

Comment: Thank you! Like this : $('.link').click(function() {
        $(this).parents(".element").siblings().stop().animate({opacity: 0.4}, 300);
        $('.link').click(function() {
        $not(this).stop().animate({opacity: 1.0}, 300);
        });
});  It works. But when I click on an other element, it stay at 0.4 opacity.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/l2aelba/DrFvX/2/ @lolo I dont know what you want , click `.link` to set opacity to 0.3 or 1 ?

Comment: This is Ok for : $('.link').click(function() {.  I just want to make opacity on element (not on link). this fiddle(http://jsfiddle.net/DrFvX/1/) works for the opacity on element. That's the result that I want. However if you click on an other .element, the opacity stay always at 0.4.